# CalculateField() not working with list of values

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I'm trying to calculate a series of fields in a featureclass using a list of fields and a list of values. The code runs as intended with exit code 0, but does not actually calculate the fields in the featureclass. I've tried several ways to format the "value" in the `CalculateField()` but haven't had any luck.

```
import arcpy


def main():
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    arcpy.env.workspace = r"G:\Python_Tool_Scratch.gdb"

    # get parameters
    permit_fc = r"P:\DEV.gdb\Admin\Permit"
    aop_id = "AOI_ID = 'CB'"
    forest_poly = r"P:\DEV.gdb\Operational\Forest_poly"

    # select permit to calculate
    permit = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(permit_fc, '', where_clause=aop_id)

    # select related polygons
    polygons = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation(forest_poly, '', permit)

    # calculate statistics
    out_table = r"stats"
    fields = [['TotVol', 'sum'], ['Vol_ha', 'mean'], ['Vol_Harvested', 'sum'], ['harvested_area_ha', 'sum'], ['bSPerc', 'mean'], ['BfPerc', 'mean'], ['wSPerc', 'mean'], ['Area_ha', 'sum']]
    arcpy.analysis.Statistics(polygons, out_table, fields)

    # calculate fields
    fields = ['SUM_TotVol', 'MEAN_Vol_ha', 'SUM_Vol_Harvested', 'SUM_harvested_area_ha', 'MEAN_bSPerc', 'MEAN_bFPerc','MEAN_wSPerc', 'SUM_Area_ha']
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(out_table, fields) as cursor:
        stats = cursor.next()

    fields = ['Volume', 'VolHa', 'TotHarvVol', 'TotHarvArea', 'CompBS', 'CompBF', 'CompWS', 'Area_ha']

    for field, value in zip(fields, stats):
        if value is None:
            print(f"No Value Found for {field}")
        else:
            print(f"Calc Field {field} || {value}")
            arcpy.management.CalculateField(permit, field, f"{value}", "PYTHON")


main()
```